# Android - scrollable listview in home screen widget

Tags: android, listview, widget, scrollable

I've problem, that i want to create a home screen widget with listview inside, which should be scrollable. I read on docs page, that listview is only supported in remoteview from 3.0 android.

But still i think, this is not completely true, or i am missing something. Ok, when i tried do add listview to my home screen diget, i get error: `class not allowed to be inflated android.widget.listview`. BUT on my phone i have android 2.2.3 and i am able to add home screen widget (its some email application widget) which shows SCROLLABLE list of my emails, look here:

http://i50.tinypic.com/2gslq2q.png

And my question is: How is this possible and how to do it, in which way? Im googling few hours, but have absolutely no idea how is this possible (maybe dynamically generate items int vertical linear layout and create manualy scroller on right side, but it sound terrible complicated).![enter image description here][1]

EDIT: maybe its possible to generate long list of items into linear layout and detecting, if user is moving up or down with finger...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read on docs page, that listview is only supported in remoteview from 3.0 android.

Correct.

> i am able to add home screen widget (its some email application widget) which shows SCROLLABLE list of my emails

That is not an app widget. That is a feature of that home screen implementation.

> maybe its possible to generate long list of items into linear layout and detecting, if user is moving up or down with finger...

No, sorry.

Comment: please be more specific, u're writing "That is not an app widget. That is a feature of that home screen implementation.", what does it mean? How they implemented scrollable listview (or something that looks exactly like listview)?

Comment: @qkx: "what does it mean?" -- it means exactly what I wrote. When you press the HOME button of a phone, all you are doing is bringing an activity to the foreground that happens to implement the home screen. That *activity* is welcome to have a `ListView` in it, whereas an app widget cannot. That activity is welcome to claim that it has an email "widget" that uses a `ListView`, even though it is not really an app widget. You can tell this by installing *some other home screen* off the Play Store, and noticing that you cannot get to this email "app widget" anymore.

Comment: so on other phones (with other implementations of home screen) it should not work? Well, I extracted the apk of that application, and checked a layout file - they used some component named "com.lge.appwidget.Andy_EmailListView" - as i understand, its something like LG developed component, which runs only on LG phones resp. on home screens like mine?